# Xcode v7.2 - New Radio Buttons: How to find selected

Tags: swift, macos, interface-builder, xcode7, nsbutton

I am attempting to detect which Radio Button is currently selected using Xcode 7's new Radio Button template (NSButton).

I have created a simple action that will print to log the title of the sender when a radio button is selected.  This does work:

```
@IBAction func radioButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject)
    {
    print(sender.selectedCell()!.title);
    }
```

But what I am really looking for is the ability to know which radio button is selected elsewhere in my codes (specifically on an IBAction for a button click).  I have tried:

```
@IBAction func uploadButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject)
    {
    print (radioButton.selectedCell()!.title);
    }
```

This does compile and execute, the problem is it always gives me the title of the first radio button not the one that is actually selected.

Any ideas?

---

The "closest" I can get (which is not very clean, but works "kinda") is to see if *radioButton.cell?state = 1*.  This tells me that the first radio button is selected.  But this is a very poor way to code this and only allows for 2 radio button options.

```
if (radioButton.cell?.state == 1)
    {
    print ("Radio 1 Selected");
    }
else
    {
    print ("Radio 2 Selected");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a method for this.

First I setup a variable to store which item was checked (and pre-set the value to the value I want for the first radio button)

```
var databaseUploadMethod = "trickle-add";
```

Then I compare to see the title value of the selected item:

```
@IBAction func radioButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject)
    {
    if ((sender.selectedCell()!.title) == "Trickle Add")
        {
        databaseUploadMethod = "trickle-add";
        }
    else if ((sender.selectedCell()!.title) == "Bulk Add All Now")
        {
        databaseUploadMethod = "bulk-add";
        }
    }
```

For reference:  I have two radio buttons, the first has a title of "Trickle Add" and the second is "Bulk Add All Now".  Those are the values I am comparing in my if statement.

Answer (score 2):

Use the identifier or tag property in Interface Builder to distinguish between radio buttons like:

```
@IBAction func selectOption(sender: AnyObject) {
    let id:String = sender.identifier!!
    case "first identifier":
        // do some stuff
        // ...
    default:
        // do default stuff
}
```

Another option would be a switch-case statement and defining outlets for each radio button like:

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstOption: NSButton!
@IBOutlet weak var secondOption: NSButton!
@IBOutlet weak var thirdOption: NSButton!

@IBAction func selectOption(sender: AnyObject) {

    switch sender as! NSButton {
    case firstOption:
        print("firstOption")
    case secondOption:
        print("secondOption")
    case thirdOption:
        print("thirdOption")
    default:
        print("won't be called when exhaustive but must always be implemented")
    }
}
```